# RC522 RFID Module under heavy load?

Tags: rfid

We are planning to use RC522 RFID Module with RaspPi for authenticating guests at an event and am wondering if this is a good idea as there could be up to 500 guests / hour. Our system will simply read and authenticate the RFID via http to the main frame and return true/false based on RestFul API. Any help in this will be appreciated.

Comment: Try to do tests, clock stuff, and do memory/cpu profiles. `top` is a good start.

Comment: Hi @Amjad Khan,Welcome and nice to meet you. Ah, Let me see, you have two timing worries related to (1) Database, (2) RFID. For database, you may like to give more details, eg is it on cloud or in edge, is it huge, if yes, is it OK to off load only the revelant part to Rpi? For RFID, I don't think you should have any worries, because you can use 10Mb/s SPI.  And you can setup multiple Rpi's to short the guest queues.  Me electronic hobbyist and have many cheap MFRC522 modules in hand.  In case you are using python, I am happy to help debugging.  Cheers.  PS - See references next comment..

Comment: References: (1) MFRC-522 13.56 Mhz RFID (SPI 10Mb/s, UART 1228.8 kBd, I2C 3440kBd) - US$1
https://de.aliexpress.com/item/1260729519.html, (2) MFRC522 Datasheet - NXP 2016
https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MFRC522.pdf